# How to deploy a report to Jasper Server

Tags: java, jdbc, jasper-reports, ireport, jasperserver

I tried to deploy a report to my jasper server. I followed this tutorial: http://randomallsorts.blogspot.de/2009/12/jasper-reports-how-to-deploy-report-to.html. But in the end of the day, when I tried to have a look at my report in the admin interface I just received a pretty long error which I don't understand.

> The server has encountered an error. Please excuse the inconvenience.
>   Error Message
>
> com.mysql.jdbc.Driver Error Trace
>
> com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.JSExceptionWrapper:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1516)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1361)
>   at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) at
>   java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247) at
>   com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.common.service.impl.JdbcDriverServiceImpl.loadDriverFromExistingClassLoaders(JdbcDriverServiceImpl.java:535)
>   at
>   com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.common.service.impl.JdbcDriverServiceImpl.register(JdbcDriverServiceImpl.java:130)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) at
>   org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:318)
>   at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:196)
>   at $Proxy35.register(Unknown Source) at
>   com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.DbcpDataSourceFactory.registerDriver(DbcpDataSourceFactory.java:58)
>   at
>   com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.DbcpDataSourceFactory.createPooledDataSource(DbcpDataSourceFactory.java:50)
>   at
>   com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.JdbcReportDataSourceServiceFactory.getPoolDataSource(JdbcReportDataSourceServiceFactory.java:145)
>   at
>   com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.JdbcReportDataSourceServiceFactory.createService(JdbcReportDataSourceServiceFactory.java:128)
>   at
>   com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.EngineServiceImpl.createDataSourceService(EngineServiceImpl.java:1763)
>   at
>   com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.EngineServiceImpl.fillReport(EngineServiceImpl.java:1651)
>   at
>   com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.EngineServiceImpl$ReportFill.runReport(EngineServiceImpl.java:1022)
>   at
>   com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.EngineServiceImpl$ReportRunnable.run(EngineServiceImpl.java:897)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619) Error Message
>
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver Error Trace
>
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1516)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1361)
>   at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) at
>   java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247) at
>   com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.common.service.impl.JdbcDriverServiceImpl.loadDriverFromExistingClassLoaders(JdbcDriverServiceImpl.java:535)
>   at
>   com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.common.service.impl.JdbcDriverServiceImpl.register(JdbcDriverServiceImpl.java:130)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) at
>   org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:318)
>   at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:196)
>   at $Proxy35.register(Unknown Source) at
>   com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.DbcpDataSourceFactory.registerDriver(DbcpDataSourceFactory.java:58)
>   at
>   com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.DbcpDataSourceFactory.createPooledDataSource(DbcpDataSourceFactory.java:50)
>   at
>   com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.JdbcReportDataSourceServiceFactory.getPoolDataSource(JdbcReportDataSourceServiceFactory.java:145)
>   at
>   com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.JdbcReportDataSourceServiceFactory.createService(JdbcReportDataSourceServiceFactory.java:128)
>   at
>   com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.EngineServiceImpl.createDataSourceService(EngineServiceImpl.java:1763)
>   at
>   com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.EngineServiceImpl.fillReport(EngineServiceImpl.java:1651)
>   at
>   com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.EngineServiceImpl$ReportFill.runReport(EngineServiceImpl.java:1022)
>   at
>   com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.EngineServiceImpl$ReportRunnable.run(EngineServiceImpl.java:897)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

Does anybody have a clue what could be wrong there ? I am sorry but I am really a ireport amateur.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you should install the driver on your Jasper Server.

1. Go to the web interface with a user in the role ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR
2. On the tree view, you can create a folder to hold your datasource
3. In that folder, right click and add a data source
4. Give it a meaningful name for you and upload the com.mysql.jdbc.Driver (if not already present).

   1. Note: if you did a manual WAR installation, you probably installed the driver already.
   2. Download the driver here http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/
5. Check the jdbc url. Should be something like `jdbc:mysql://your_host/your_database`

   1. Small hack is to check your max allow packet setting in your MYSQL server and set it accordingly in your jdbc url. On MYSQL driver, check it using this command:
   2. `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_allowed_packet';`
   3. Then set the url to: `jdbc:mysql://your_host/your_database?maxAllowedPacket=WHATEVER_SIZE_YOU_GOT`
6. Check the username, password and timezone and test the connection.
7. Edit the report on the web interface and set the datasource as being this one.

When you upload a new report, either via web interface or iReport Designer, assign this data source.

Good luck, hope it solves your problem :)

Answer (score 2):

try using this guide..
Seems like it cannot find the mysql driver to connect.

http://jasperserver.sourceforge.net/docs/3-5-0/JasperServer-User-Guide.pdf

Comment: True, I had to install the mysql-connector-java.jar and choose the path to install the driver.